# PresentModalViewController view is shifted with no animation

Tags: iphone, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a new view controller on the iPhone which I call using the following line of code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

This works great if animation is on, but I am looking to have an instant switch. The problem is when I set animation to NO, the whole view shifts 20px to the right (it is always in landscape mode) as if there is a status bar but in portrait mode!?

In this example the yellow space is the new view controller.

[alt text http://www.james-ingham.info/pics/iphoneshift.png](http://www.james-ingham.info/pics/iphoneshift.png)

I've tried this in a new project and the same thing happens. It may be a bug but does anyone have a fix? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the value of the `controller.view.frame` property, and make sure that it is correct.  Most likely you will notice that the `origin.x` value is 20.  However, I'm perplexed as to why the frame fits when animated.

Comment: Hmm... I forgot to mention I'm using OpenFeint. Maybe this is the problem. Will get back to you on that...

Comment: Not sure how hacky this is but when I present the modal view I simply set the origin values to 0 and it's solved. However this isn't being changed anywhere else! It works tho :)